# Keep run into "ETIMEOUT, Timeout while contacting DNS servers" error when making http request in node.js

Tags: networking, node.js

This error happens whenever the node process make a http request to get user's information from a web API.

The scenario is :
I'm running a TCP server using node, and when it get "login" request from a client, it will send a http GET request to another web API to retrieve the user's information.
While users increasing, the node process starts to throw the **"ETIMEOUT"** error when retrieving user's info. And once if the error happened, all the request after that will throw the same error.
I've tried to perform the same request with *wget* but everything is fine, so I think maybe it's not a network problem.

And strangely, after increasing the open file limit to 10,0000 using *ulimit -n*, it goes well until the next level user increment.

The fetch function is here:

```
fetchUserInfo = function(callback) {
  var http = require('http');
  var opt = { 
    agent: false,
    host: 'www.someapi.net',
    port: 80,
    path: '/userInfo.php'
  }
  var body = ''; 
  var req = http.request(opt, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      if(callback) {
        callback(body);
      }
    });
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    sys.log("User info fetch error: " + e.message);
    if(callback) {
      callback();
    }   
  }); 
  req.end();
}
```

My environment is Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 with node v0.4.10.

Comment: We also run into the same error. If you watch "ls -l /proc/$PID/fd" is there a lot of old socket descriptors listed as open? I have no solution but it looks like node sometimes does not close old sockets and in the long run runs out of either fd:s for more socets or sockets entirely.

Comment: There are some socket descriptors listed but the amount is around 3000, and it seems likes to be other tcp connections.